# How to get spring context into testcases

Tags: spring

I am using maven project, with spring jpa.
how to test DAO methods in test cases.
And how to get spring context into the test cases

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SpringJUnit4ClassRunner](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html) JUnit runner to setup spring in JUnit tests.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/applicationContext-1.xml", "/test-config.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
public class MyTest {

  @Autowired
  private MySpringBean bean;
}
```

With the `DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener` you can inject spring beans in your test classes.

Have a look at the very extensive [Spring Testing documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html).

Answer (score 0):

Take help from below code to inject application context

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.clas)
public class ControllerIntegrationTests {

   @Autowired
   private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

}
```

If you are using Java based configuration then take help from the above code, if xml is being used as configuring app then replace `classes` with `locations`  example as below

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
```

or

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/test-context.xml")
```